# How to obtain round peaks instead of triangular peaks when smoothing an input?

Tags: smoothing

I have a signal (in blue) that I would like to smooth out (in red, moving average).

I would like to get red peaks to look more round than triangular and at the same time their width would become closer to the original ones.

[image]

Do you know / can you suggest a filter that would yield such result ?

**Background:**

The input is the zero-crossing rate from a song, for building a colored waveform as I've tried in this question : [Coloring a waveform with spectral centroid or by other means](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8997/coloring-a-waveform-with-spectral-centroid-or-by-other-means)

Here's the result of the new approach:

(unprocessed)

[image]

(ideal result, cheated somehow here using a post, expensive gaussian blur)

[image]

**Update**

Here's the result, using **@Laurent Duval** answer:

[image]

Also, I still need to try all of your suggestions again as my input/initial take was buggy, surprisingly now the ZCR yields better output than using FFTW out of the box (pics on the right):

[image]

**Update 2**

Simple moving average (green: 1-pass, gold: 2-passes)

[image]

Comment: can you share the excel file?

Comment: Here it is ! http://1drv.ms/1KeVzIh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understand "round" versus "triangular". Yet in chemistry, least-squares polynomial fitting filters are used to keep the smooth shape of spectra peaks. The most famous are the [Savitzky–Golay filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter). They have been revived in signal processing by a recent overview paper by R. W. Shafer: [What Is a Savitzky-Golay Filter?](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee123/fa11/docs/SGFilter.pdf) (2011).

Comment: Well, I would like those red peaks to be wider than they are now, I guess they would look more round/sinusoid-like, if that makes sense ! Anyway, going to dig on your suggestion and come here for feedback, thank you !

Comment: Your solution looks promising, I haven't coded the filter by myself but I think I've found a pretty good implementation based on "Numerical recipes in C" (http://altaxo.sourceforge.net/AltaxoClassRef/). Could you suggest some parameters regarding my update section in the question ? Basically, I would to keep each of the second bump to roughly the same level instead of being halved. Thank you !

Comment: Thank you for the update, excellent news. As for the parameters, I do not have access to your sampling and signal properties, thus not able to have a guess. The definition and explanation of SG filters in Numerical Recipes is pretty good to, and might help you to this respect

Comment: Thank you, it does really address the initial concern, I'll read the article in detail.

Answer (score 3):

Use two or three passes of moving average (can be pipelined).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @jojek: I don't agree.

Comment: Going to give it a try and come back here.

Comment: See my update, basically it works but there's latency being introduced and original level is drastically reduced ... is there any way to overcome these two issues ? thank you.

Comment: You don't seem to have the latency problem in @Laurent Duval's solution. How come ?

Comment: Lowpass filtering indeed lessens the high frequencies. You can't achieve much better with a linear and simple filter.

Comment: I guess we hit the limits of the moving average for this specific issue. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try a small Gaussian filter.

An approximation to the Gaussian can be achieved by applying a moving average filter multiple times.

Comment: Ok, going to give it a try and come back.

Comment: Thanks ! it works well too though the signal shape degrades quite quickly.

Answer (score 0):

In the question Aybe implied that the red curve is a moving average of the blue curve. That doesn't look correct to me. (It seems to me that a moving-averaged output would not have the sharp peaks seen in the red curve.) My first thought was to suggest, as Yves Daoust did, a moving average filter as a possible answer to the question. If Yves and I had access the the blue curve's sample values we could see if a true moving average filter will satisfy Aybe.

Comment: That's a moving average trendline I've added using the wizard in Excel. Here's the file : http://1drv.ms/1KeVzIh